# Select Card In Flutter Listview

Tags: listview, select, dynamic, flutter, setstate

So I have a listview.builder in Flutter. It returns an InkWell that has a Card in Container as a child. The container has a color that has to change when the card is tapped. I want to do this with `setState()` but it won't work. It doesn't seem to work to set state inside a listview. How do I make the cards dynamic????

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.cyan,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 3,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

          var mycolor=Colors.white;

          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {

                setState(() {
                  if (mycolor == Colors.white) {
                    mycolor=Colors.grey[300];
                  } else {
                    mycolor=Colors.white;
                  }
                });

            },
            child: Card(
              color: mycolor,
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,

              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  // list of colors to map to specific index of list items
  List<Color> _color = [
    Colors.green[400],
    Colors.green[400],
    Colors.green[400]
  ];

  // when tapped, toggle the color
  void _toggleColor(_index) {
    setState(() {
      if (_color[_index] == Colors.white) {
        _color[_index] = Colors.green[400];
      } else {
        _color[_index] = Colors.white;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 3,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  return this._toggleColor(index);
                },
                child: Card(
                    color: this._color[index], // get value from state object
                    child: Container(width: 100, height: 100)));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems correct. Would be more useful if some explanation could be added why this change is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend declaring the `mycolor` variable in the widget state at the beginning like this:

```
Color mycolor = Colors.white;
```

Then on your onTap function you could do something like this:

```
if (mycolor === Colors.white) {
  setState(() {
    mycolor = Colors.grey[300];
  }
} else {
 setState(() {
  mycolor = Colors.white;
 }
}
```